# Passing child, instance, variable to parent in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to pass an instance variable from a child class to the parent class?
I have a class `Borrower` that is inherited by a class `Student` and a class `Professor`. I want to implement a method for them to borrow books. Since borrowing books is something both do, I want to write the method in the `Borrower` class. My problem is, that the child classes can borrow a different number of books. Would it be possible to pass that number into the parent class (`Borrower`)? The number for each instance changes according to how many books have been borrowed by that`Student` or `Professor`

borrower.rb

```
class Borrower < Person
  attr_reader :id
  def initialize(name, surname, id)
    super(name, surname)
    @books = []
    @id = id
  end
  def books_to_borrow(books)
    if books.length <= leftToBorrow
      @books = books
    else
      puts "You can only borrow #{leftToBorrow} books"
      return 0
    end
  end
end
```

student.rb

```
class Student < Borrower
  attr_reader :studentType
  def initialize(name, surname, studentType, id)
    super(name, surname, id)
    @studentType = studentType #Where studentType is 0 for Bachelors and 1 for Masters.
    @leftToBorrow = 5 if @studentType == 1
    @leftToBorrow = 4 if @studentType == 0
  end
end
```

professor.rb

```
class Professor < Borrower
  def initialize(name, surname, id)
    super(name, surname, id)
    @leftToBorrow = 70
  end
end
```

**EDIT**
I tried adding the variable I want to the `Borrower` class, so now I have access to it. I initialize it to 0, then the child changes it's value, so it changes in the parent too. However, I still think there's a better way of doing it.

Do you find my approach wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: please publish the code you have and tried

Comment: @peter I updated my answer with code.

Comment: @sawa
`Student` and `Professor` are children of `Borrower`, doesn't this mean that `Borrower` is inherited by those classes?

Comment: You could add `attr_reader :leftToBorrow` to `Borrower`. (and you should use snake_case instead of camelCase for variables and methods)

Comment: Sorry, I got confused with the description. I edited, then reverted the question.

Comment: You could make a class for Bachelor and Master but much depends on how you are going to store the data.

Comment: @peter I could but the functionality of it would be close to 0. For me, a variable works better to distinguish bsc and msc, at the moment